# How to update mysql version in xampp (error with innodb_additional_mem_pool_size)

Tags: mysql, xampp, upgrade, mariadb, mysqlupgrade

I'm trying to `upgrade mysql` in `xamp`. I'm using `laravel` which requires `mariaDB v10.2.2`. So I downloaded the `latest msi package` from the `mariaDB website`. Now I followed following points to install the same:

- Install MySQL to C:\TEMP.
- Make old installation folder to mysql_old.
- copy the following folders "bin, include, lib, share, support-files" to xamp\mysql\ folder. **I didn't copied the data folder**
- Copied the my.ini file from old installation to new installation in xamp\mysql\bin\ folder
- Copied the old data folder to new mysql folder

Now after doing this I tried to start mysql from the control panel and following error displays:

[image: XAMP Control Panel error screenshot]

Now while checking the error log I found this:

```
2017-02-25 12:31:56 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2017-02-25 12:31:56 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-02-25 12:31:56 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-02-25 12:31:56 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-02-25 12:31:56 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2017-02-25 12:31:56 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2017-02-25 12:31:56 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-02-25 12:31:56 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-02-25 12:31:56 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2017-02-25 12:31:56 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'F:\xamp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2017-02-25 12:31:57 5736 [Note] InnoDB: File 'F:\xamp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2017-02-25 12:31:57 5736 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-02-25 12:31:57 5736 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-02-25 12:31:57 5736 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-02-25 12:31:57 5736 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.14 started; log sequence number 2361919
2017-02-25 12:31:57 11468 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from F:\xamp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2017-02-25 12:31:57 11468 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 170225 12:31:57
2017-02-25 12:31:57 5736 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-02-25 12:31:57 5736 [ERROR] f:\xamp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: unknown variable 'innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2M'
2017-02-25 12:31:57 5736 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Now following is my.ini file:

```
# Example MySQL config file for small systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
# doesn't use much resources.
#
# You can copy this file to
# F:/xamp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is F:/xamp/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client] 
# password       = your_password 
port            = 3306 
socket          = "F:/xamp/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "F:/xamp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "F:/xamp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "F:/xamp/tmp" 
datadir = "F:/xamp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"

# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir = "F:/xamp/mysql/lib/plugin/" 

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
#skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "F:/xamp/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = "F:/xamp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "F:/xamp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "F:/xamp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="F:/xamp/mysql/share/charsets"

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

Please look if I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simply remove this line from `my.ini`:

```
    innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
```

It was "deprecated in MySQL 5.6.3, are removed in MySQL 5.7.4."

(If my notes are correct, it has been "unused" since 4.1.0!)

Comment: If the my.ini file of your old installation is not the default one of Xampp install (example: settings based on  my-huge.ini, my-large.ini, etc.), you must take care with other directives that were also removed from MySQL 5.7, like 'thread_concurrency' (remove it!), 'key_buffer' (replace it by key_buffer_size).

Answer (score 10):

> To Upgrade MySql included in XAMPP (I did it on a Windows system):
>
> 1. Rename your Mysql directory to some other name.
> 2. Download the .msi file from the MariaDB link https://downloads.mariadb.org/.
> 3. Run .msi.  Change the install directory to your Mysql location under                XAMPP.
> 4. After completion, copy the old my.ini from the original mysql/bin directory to your new mysql/bin directory.
> 5. You should be able to start Mysql from the XAMPP control panel.

I found the solution here
http://www.mynotebucket.com/update-mysql-under-xmpp/

Answer (score 1):

What I did and saved my life:

1. Rename xampp/mysql/data to xampp/mysql/anyname_data (or any name of your choice)
2. Create a new folder and name it > data in xampp/mysql
3. Copy all your xampp/mysql/backup files and folder to newly created xampp/mysql/data folder
4. Now which previous database you want to work with copy that folder from
   xampp/mysql/anyname_data to newly created xampp/mysql/data folder
5. Restart Xampp with or without "run as administrator"

Amazingly! your database is intact in phpmyadmin.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Download the latest xampp version and move projects from the old xampp directory.