# Unable to Start mysql after Update from 5.0.12 to 5.7.18

Tags: mysql, xampp, updates

I tried to update MySQL from 5.0.12 to 5.7.18 but unable to start MySQL after upgrade. I performed following steps.

- I downloaded Zip Archive file from [MySQL Community Server](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/).
- I extracted the archive file in Temp Folder.
- I renamed the mysql folder to mysql_backup
- I created a new mysql folder and pasted all the newly extracted files in that folder
- I copied data folder from old mysql_backup folder to newly created mysql folder.
- I copied my.ini from old mysql_backup folder to new mysql folder's bin directory.
- I tried to start mysql service but it gives error.

[image]

- I removed following line as per this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453124/how-to-update-mysql-version-in-xamp) but still same error.
  `innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M`

There is nothing in error log of mysql. It seems to be my.ini issue. Please help me out.

Comment: Are you running the control panel in administrator mode ?   "Improper privileges" is one of the possible causes.

Comment: Yes, I am using "Run as Administrator" specifically for Control Panel

Comment: What are you updating _from_? Did you read the release notes of the interim versions to see what has changed?

Comment: Updated in post, I had been updating from 5.0.12. No, actually there were too many interim versions to read the release notes from so I directly jumped to this version 5.7.18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I have found the answer using Windows Event Viewer. The issue was with the below line in [mysqld] section which I have commented-out/removed from my.ini file and now MySQL have started:

`key_buffer = 16M`

After commenting this out this line will be:

`#key_buffer = 16M`

Please do check your Windows Event Viewer for more clues to the errors in XAMPP Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to move the `my.ini` file from `/data` folder to `/bin` folder