# It does not open correctly xampp what should I do

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

xampp throws me these errors with apache and mysql.
he tried to change ports and shut down the firewall and it doesn't work, I also gave him administrator privileges and nothing.[enter link description here](https://i.gyazo.com/8e5d99a091cf6f1c7da6831822ad580e.png)

Answer (score 0):

you didn't provide much information I checked the errors in the attached pic
so Try this

- 1-exit Xampp server
- 2-go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data directory
- 3-delete the ibdata1 file
- 4-restart xampp server

Comment: That didn't work ... what other additional information can I offer to help me?

Comment: ok try this solution there is multiple problems causing that error try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453124/how-to-update-mysql-version-in-xampp-error-with-innodb-additional-mem-pool-size